# load data infile with counting duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I have a single column csv file containing duplicate records. I have more than ten thousands records.So I am using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Example data:

```
ID

1
2
3
2
2
1
2
```

The mysql table is called 'huts'.

My first question is if it is possible to count how many duplicate rows are there for each row while inserting the data in mysql table 'huts'.So I would like to see the populated huts table as below

```
ID    count

1     2
2     4
3     1
```

My second question is if the above is not possible then my current working code returns the following

```
ID

1 
2 
3 

$insert_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' 
                    INTO table huts
                    (id)
                    ";
    if (!mysql_query($insert_query)) {
         echo "Can't insert student record : " . mysql_error($connection);
    } else {
         echo "You have successfully insert records into huts table";
    }
```

The table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `huts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=116 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The database storage engine is 'MyISAM'

There is no unique key declared but why the query is ignoring the duplicate rows.I expected that the query should insert all the rows no matter if there is any duplicate.

Comment: Your only field is an auto_increment field? And its primary key? And you're asking why it doesn't insert duplicates....

Comment: ahhh..sorry got it now.Thanks. Any thought on the first question.

Comment: Not while doing the insert, but afterwards `select Id, count(*) from table group by id`

Comment: I have to create another table then and insert the count with the Id.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Auto increment and primary key options from your table field if you don't care about duplicated data

Comment: Thanks Guj. Sorted the second issue.