# MYSQL LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE could not update duplicate record

Tags: mysql, duplicates, load-data-infile

I want to import bulk data from XML file into my database.

I am using the following query:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '$fullpath'
REPLACE INTO TABLE `patients`ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ApptOutput>'
```

There is a unique key in XML data called `appt_id` and I have made this `appt_id` as unique in my database table.

Data is inserting well but if there is any duplicate entry occurs, it removes the old entry and inserts a new row.
I also related the patient table by primary key `id` with another table.

Now, the problem is that on every duplicate entry it removes the primary key also and inserts a new entry every time.

Is there any way to update data without deleting old entry? 
Means I want to make two field same as it, primary key `id` and unique field from The XML.

Unique id in XML is a string, I can't make it as primary key.

Conclusion: I just want to update duplicate entry instead of deleting old one and insert new one.

I have gone through these link also but not much useful [load data infile with counting duplicate rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213516/load-data-infile-with-counting-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: Since the load xml has exactly the same options and behaviour as the plain load data statement, these questions are essentially the same.